# Linux: Passing var to awk not working

Tags: linux, awk

I'm trying to extract lines between 2 patterns using awk while the patterns are passed as variables but it's not working for me.

file.txt content:

```
[Data from server]  
line 1  
line 2  
line 3  

[Data from client]  
line 1  
line 2  
line 3
```

Without variables:
Command: `awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1};/data/ && /server/{f=1} /^$/{f=0} f' file.txt`

Result:

```
[Data from server]  
line 1  
line 2  
line 3
```

With variable:

```
awk -v var=$myVar 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1};/data/ && /myVar/{f=1} /^$/{f=0} f' file.txt
```

I'm getting empty result !

Please help

Comment: Never use the word "pattern" as it's ambiguous - replace "pattern" in your question with whatever it is you mean: `string` or `regexp` or something else. Also state if you're looking for an exact match only or just a partial match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `~` operator, the variable will get interpreted as a regex:

```
$0 ~ variable
```

($0 is the whole line)

It should be:

```
awk -v var="$myVar" 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1};/data/ && $0 ~ var{f=1} /^$/{f=0} f' file.txt
```

Comment: The command returns: [Data from server]
line 1
line 2
line 3
[Data from client]
line 1
line 2
line 3

Comment: I had the wrong variable name. Edited.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Working :)

Comment: Glad to see it is working for you